# Error installing Vim with Homebrew (checking for tgetent()... configure: error: NOT FOUND!)

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew

After running `brew install vim`, I get this error:

```
checking for tgetent()... configure: error: NOT FOUND!
      You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
      Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
```

Not sure how to go about fixing this.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific problems did you encounter? Also possibly off-topic for SO? Not sure...

Comment: It is often worth trying "brew doctor"

Comment: For CentOS, you would need this library `sudo yum install ncurses-devel`

Answer (score 1):

You need to install developer tools from Xcode before. Or set up your env handly but you might have other binaries missing later. So I recommend you to install Xcode. And then developer tools. And finally get Vim ;). I even think that Vim is installed by default with developer tools.

Get it here :

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12

Comment: I re-installed Xcode and downloaded the command line tools, but I'm still getting the same error when I run brew install vim

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well. When running `brew doctor`, I found an `ncurses5-config` in the path, which seemed to be confusing homebrew. I uninstalled the chefdk, installed the latest xcode, run `brew doctor` to ensure the library is gone, and then run `brew install vim`.

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/finstyle-config
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/ncurses5-config
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/ncursesw5-config
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/pkg-config
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/xml2-config
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/xslt-config
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Mac 10.11.4

```
brew install vim --with-tlib
```

You might also want to use `--with-override-system-vi` flag as well